# need help, cant use react bootsrap

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

i need help i cant make my react app work when i try to add react bootsrap, my console said compile succefult but the app does not load, this is my code so far:

```
import React from 'react'
import Navbar  from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar'
import Container  from 'react-bootstrap/Container'
const Nav = () => {
  return (
    <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark">
      <Container>
      <Navbar.Brand href="#home">Navbar</Navbar.Brand>
      <Nav className="me-auto">
        <Nav.Link href="#home">Home</Nav.Link>
        <Nav.Link href="#features">Features</Nav.Link>
        <Nav.Link href="#pricing">Pricing</Nav.Link>
      </Nav>
      </Container>
    </Navbar>
  )
}

export default Nav
```

this is my index js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
// or send to an analytics endpoint. 
reportWebVitals();
```

and this is my app js:

```
/* import logo from './logo.svg'; */
import './App.css';
import Nav from './components/nabvar/Nav';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {/* <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header> */}
      <Nav/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

In theory everything should be working, I do not understand why the application does not load and mozzila firefox tells me that I have to stop the page because it is slowing down and that I should stop it

Comment: Hmm the code looks fine to me. Is this everything?

Comment: In Nav Component, shouldn't it be Navbar.Nav instead of just Nav. I think it is trying to re-render your custom Nav component again and again.